# Borel-Cantelli's II lemma and the independence assumption

Tags: probability-theory

Let $E_{1},E_{2},....$ be a sequence of independent events. If $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(E_{n})=\infty$ then $\mathcal{P}(\displaystyle\limsup_{n}E_{n})$=1 i.e the probability that infinitely many events occur is 1.

What easy example one can give to show that the lemma fails if the dependence condition is omitted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $A$ some event with $0 < P(A) < 1$ and set $E_n := A$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Then $(E_n)$ is dependent, and $\sum P(E_n) = \infty$. But as $\limsup E_n = A$, we have $P(\limsup E_n) = P(A) < 1$.

---

Addendum: For $n \ne m$ we have 
$$ P(E_n \cap E_m) = P(A \cap A) = P(A) \ne P(A)^2 = P(E_n)P(E_m), $$
(as $P(A) \notin \{0,1\}$), so $E_n$ and $E_m$ are dependent. On the other hand, for $n \in \mathbb N$:
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{k \ge 1} P(E_k) &\ge \sum_{k=1}^n P(E_k)\\
          &= n \cdot P(A)
\end{align*}
as hence $\sum_k P(E_k) = \infty$, as $P(A) > 0$.

Comment: How do we know the sequence $(E_{n})$ is dependent? How do they depend on one another? $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(E_{n})=\infty$?

Comment: @HeidiE Added something.

Comment: @@martini thanks for the elaboration. Can you explain please what have you done in the last inequalities with sums? $\displaystyle\sum_{k\ge 1}P(E_{k})...$

Comment: As $P(E_k) \ge 0$ for all $k$, we have $\sum_{k\ge 1} P(E_k) \ge \sum_{k=1}^n P(E_k)$. Now $P(E_k) = P(A)$ for all $k$, hence $\sum_{k=1}^n P(E_k) = nP(A)$. Does this help you, @HeidiE

Comment: @@martini: Yes definitely. Many thanks!