# Second Borel-Cantelli without independence assumption

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

The second Borel-Cantelli lemma says

> Let $(X,F,\mu)$ be a probability space. Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots\in F$ be independent, and let $A=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \bigcup_{j=i}^\infty A_j$ (i.e. the probability that infinitely many $A_i$'s occur). If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_i)=\infty$, then $\mu(A)=1$.

One [easy example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509803/borel-cantellis-ii-lemma-and-the-independence-assumption) to show that if the independence condition is omitted, then the theorem is not true, is to take $A_1=A_2=\ldots$. Is there an easy example where the sets $A_i$ are mutually distinct?

Comment: I'm not sure regarding the terminology, so let me ask this: do you mean that $\bigcap A_j=\emptyset$? (They cannot be pairwise disjoint and have the sum of their probabilities diverge.)

Comment: @JonathanY. I mean $A_i\neq A_j$ for $i\neq j$ (*distinct*, not *disjoint*)

Comment: Thanks. I was confused about the 'mutually' part (I'd say 'pairwise distinct').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One example would be to take $\Omega=[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, and $A_i = [0,\frac{1}{i}]$.